# $\sum (\sqrt{x_k-k^2}-k)^2=0$ implies $x_k=2k^2$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, solution-verification

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ be reals numbers such that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\sqrt{x_k-k^2}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$$
>   Find all possible $n$-tuples of solution.

So, I got the following solution from the proposer of this problem. The given equation is equivalent to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\sqrt{x_k-k^2}-k)^2=0$$
Hence we have $\sqrt{x_k-k^2}=k$ for all $k$. Thus $x_k=2k^2$ $\forall k$ is the only possible solution.

But I seriously doubt this solution. The fact that $x_k$ is real does not necessarily imply $\sqrt{x_k-k^2}$ is real. So sum of squares being zero does not imply each term is zero in this case.

Comment: I think the problem implicitly assumes that $x_k\geq k^2$. If ${x_k - k^2}<0$, you get two imaginary roots, and it is ambiguous which to choose from the notation. What is the context of this problem?

Comment: I also think you are right. This problem was used in a regional contest conducted by undergrad students. So there is a possibility that the proposer himself overlooked it.

Comment: But still as I was working on the $n=2$ case, $$\sqrt{x-1}+2\sqrt{y-4}=\frac12(x+y)$$
assuming if t>0, $\sqrt{-t}=i\sqrt{t}$, I failed to produce another tuple.

Comment: If you want to explore possible complex solutions, it may be fruitful to consider polar coordinate parameterizations of $X = x-1$ and $Y = y-4$, rewrite RHS as $(X+Y+5)/2$, and note that each square root has two branches ($X^{1/2} = |X|^{1/2}e^{i\theta + i k\pi})$, $k=0,1$), giving 4 possibilities on the LHS. I have no idea if you will find a solution, though.